# Communication between a BeagleBoard and an Arduino Pro Mini through an FTDI adapter

Tags: usb, arduino, beagleboard, ftdi

I'm working on a project in which i have to connect a [BeagleBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard) and an [Arduino Pro Mini](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini) for communication.

I tried the *USB-FTDI* way. I have installed all kernel modules, *ftdi-sio* , *usbserial* module, but nothing appear in */dev*. I try it in [Ångström](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution) and Ubuntu. I wanted to use [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C), but I have to know electronics. Since the BeagleBoard's *GPIOS* output is 1.8 V, I need a level converter to communicate with the Arduino.

What do I have to do to make it working?

Answer (score 2):

For I²C, I can think of two solutions readily available.

You can use SparkFun's [PCA9306 Level Translator Breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10403?) for I²C. Quote from their web page:

> The PCA9306 is a dual bidirectional I²C-bus and SMBus voltage-level
>   translator that's operational on the low side from 1.0 V to 3.6 V and
>   on the high side from 1.8 V to 5.5 V. Simply apply your low- and
>   high-side reference voltages to the VREF1 and VREF2 respectively,
>   connect your I/O and drive the Enable pin high to open bidirectional
>   voltage translation without the use of a direction pin!

[image]

---

Or you can SFE [Logic Level Converter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8745) or like circuit which is a discrete solution. Cheaper and a bit more subtle in its explanation of how it works.

---

Are you able to detect any [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus) slaves (mouse, keyboard, etc...) from the host, other than the FTDI? If not, then that would be a place to start.

Comment: thanks for replying mpflaga but i have no skills  in electronics so i need an alternate solution , and for usb i'm using usb-wireless device for network on beagleboard. i'm wondering if i can use the IDC10 RX , TX, GND, on beagleboard serial directly with RX,TX and GND on my arduino pro mini?